# margin-top and margin-bottom do not work with html a element?

Tags: html, css

i was trying to understand CSS transition property and i have understood.
but i have got another confusing stuff.
when i was giving the margin:10px; , and i saw the result on Chrome, there  were no padding-top nor padding-bottom, means there were padding-left and padding right only.
to undertand this margin, i have tried to change the a element with p element, and the margin was good.
and here is my code:

jsfiddle.net/forbloggerku/L3Mps/

i have tried to search for article about html a element related to this problem but i haven`t found it.
Please tell me the reasons about why the margin-top and margin-bottom don't work with html a element, and please give me the URL of your reasons.
thanks in advance..

Comment: To what element did you add the margin when it didn't work? You should make it an block element by using display:block; order display:inline-block;

Comment: am sorry, as shown in the code, its html a element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that an anchor tag "a" is a inline element. Those do not behave like block elements. Add display:inline-block to your CSS for the a element and that will position it correctly. Block and Inline elements each have their own rules.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following code in your anchor css

display:block;

or

display:inline-block;

margin only works on what is known as a block element.